# Inverse of an Animation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, animation, difference-equations, boundary-conditions

I was thinking, it's possible to plot inverse an animation??

```
Clear["Global`*"]
k = 0.002;a = 0.68;
1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] /. b -> 1
animation = Animate[Plot[1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
 1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[1 + (x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k], {x, 1, 100}], {b, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: `AnimationDirection -> Backward`

Comment: no, the idea is I would like to change x,y direction like to plot y^-1[x]

Answer (score 2):

For [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html), it is generally best to fix the [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) to keep the axes fixed. For a [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), specify an [`AspectRatio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k = 0.002; a = 0.68;

animation = Animate[
  ParametricPlot[
   {1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
      1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)] Sqrt[1 + (x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k], x},
   {x, 1, 100},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4000}, {0, 100}},
   AspectRatio -> 1],
  {b, 1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work :

````
ParametricPlot[x, y[x], {x, 1, 100}]

y[x] = 1/Sqrt[k] x Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/(2 - 3 b), 
   1 + 1/(2 - 3 b), -((x^(2 - 3 b) a)/k)]
```
````